# Asignar valor en ng-include, sin usar el evento ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

En un controlador B("templates/menu_lateral.html"), estoy generando contenido dinámico, en sí, estoy generando una lista y le agrego un ng-click y la clase ".items", y desde otro controlador A, no parece reconocer la función.

si pongo este contenido en el controlador A

```
$(document).on("click", ".items", function() {
    var valor=$(this).attr("include"); //tengo un attr llamado include con un valor para saber que template usar
    $scope.oIncludes={
      "tecnico": "templates/dashboard.html",
      "historia": "templates/historia_dos.html"
    }
    $scope.include=$scope.oIncludes[valor];
 })
 $scope.include="templates/dashboard.html";
```

Por defecto usara el template, "templates/dashboard.html";
Pero con ese evento de click, a pesar de pertenecer a otro controlador, la clase "items" es detectada, pero el ng-include, nunca se actualiza. 
Que puedo hacer?

Este es el template del controlador principal

```
<div ng-include="'templates/menu_lateral.html '"></div>
<div ng-include="include" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No lo hagas, es una mala idea. Nunca uses código jquery mezclado con angular, especialmente si es un evento.

Lee [https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29)

Si quieres un evento general para tu aplicación créalo en el `$rootScope` y bindealo con `ng-click` donde sea pertinente.

La razón por la que no te funciona es porque el evento `click` de jQuery no notifica al angular que hay un cambio en el `$scope` y este no actualiza la vista.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo que demuestra que el código funciona bien si usas `ng-click`.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('IncludeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.include = 'templates/dashboard.html';
    $scope.cambiaInclude = function() {
      $scope.include = $scope.include === 'templates/dashboard.html' ? 'templates/historia_dos.html' : 'templates/dashboard.html';
    }
  })
  .run(function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('', '<h1>Nada<h1>');
    $templateCache.put('templates/dashboard.html', '<h1>Dashboard<h1>');
    $templateCache.put('templates/historia_dos.html', '<h1>Historia Dos<h1>');
    $templateCache.put('templates/menu_lateral.html', '<h1>Menu lateral<h1>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="IncludeCtrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click="cambiaInclude()">Cambiar</button>
  <div ng-include="'templates/menu_lateral.html'"></div>
  <div ng-include="include"></div>
</div>
```

Puedes usar `$scope.$apply` para que se actualize la vista pero como te dice el articulo referenciado anteriormente no es algo que deberías hacer.